# UISearchController disappears when pushing a new UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uisearchcontroller, ios12

I'm currently working with an example from Raywenderlich: [UISearchController-Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/472-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started) (The finished project is at the end of their article or [here](https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2017/10/CandySearch_4_Finished.zip)) and I noticed that when I execute a search and click on one of the results, during the push transition, the UISearchController disappears. It's visible on this video: [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UEzeZ1XyZ8pr1LnGtof3aLtpxXn0fMeB)

[Before selecting a result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaXpY.png)

[During the transition to the new VC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeL2C.png)

I run this example with Xcode 10, iOS 12 (sim: iPhone 8)

Any idea / pointer would be deeply appreciated

Cheers.

Comment: Can u share any code, hard to say anything!  When you are presenting your detailviewcontroller are u setting `definesPresentationContext = true` for the detailviewcontroller? If you don't set that you may see some weird behaviors.

Comment: @lionserdar, thank you for your comment. The code is downloadable from the link I posted. Setting `definesPresentationContext` doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its default in iOS12. Just look at the Apple-Mail App. There it is the same. Actually you dont need the searchbar, when you are showing another VC

Comment: thank you for your answer. The fact that the searcher disappears when the user clicks on a result and a new VC is pushed isn't nice visually.